# ViewPager Fragment being called twice

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Ok, so I'm trying to implement a ViewPager with three pages, and to have unique content on each one, so I've set up a system where I am inflating different layouts based off of the page index. This is working as soon as i navigate, but I'm noticing that the Fragment is being called twice.

Here's my FragmentAcivity class:

```
public class TutorialScreen extends FragmentActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "TAG";
    private static final int NUM_PAGES = 3;
    private ViewPager pager; // animation handler
    private PagerAdapter adapter; // provides pages to pager

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tutorial_layout);

        // Instantiate Pager & Adapter
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        adapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
        Log.v(TAG, "Initial Page is " + pager.getCurrentItem()); // this logs '0' - which is what i want
        pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(pager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
        else {
            pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem() -1);
        }
    }

    // Pager Adapter SubClass
    private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            Log.v(TAG, "constructor"); // this logs once
            pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem());
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Log.v(TAG, "getItem " + position); // this logs twice
            return new ScreenSlidePageFragment(position); // note I've overridden the constructor
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }   
    } 
}
```

and my Fragment class:

```
public class ScreenSlidePageFragment extends Fragment {

    private static int pageIndex;
    private static final String TAG = "TAG";

    ScreenSlidePageFragment(int id) {
        pageIndex = id;
        Log.v(TAG, "Page Index is " + pageIndex); // this logs twice
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        int resID = -1;

        switch(pageIndex) {
            case 0:
                resID = R.layout.tutorial_page1;
                break;
            case 1:
                resID = R.layout.tutorial_page2;
                break;
            case 2:
                resID = R.layout.tutorial_page3;
                break;
            default:
                resID = R.layout.tutorial_page1;
                break;
        }

        Log.v(TAG, "Res Index is " + resID); // this logs twice
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(resID, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

The Log is

constructor
getItem 0
Page Index is 0
getItem 1
Page Index is 1
Res Index is 2130903043
Res Index is 2130903043

So basically it is jumping to the second page right away, regardless of whether I set the position with setCurrentItem() ...

I think that I may be cheating by trying to only have one Fragment class, instead of a separate one for each matching layout, but... this should work ?

Note that I am seeing a (I think) related issue in that the second (initial) page is showing up twice - once initially, and then after swiping to the next page again (which should be page 3?). Once I navigate to Page 3 (after two swipes) I can go all the way back to Page 1 (which should be the initial page).

Thoughts? What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: By default, fragments to the left and right (initially there is only one to the right) are loaded. This is done for performance reasons so there can be a smooth animation when paging. You can increase how many are preloaded on each side, but the minimum is 1.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense (i remember seeing that mentioned in the transformPage() method)... but why is it navigating/setting the second page ? Should I be calling setCurrentItem() elsewhere ?

Comment: Based on your log it looks like it is creating page 0 and page 1 (in the background). What is showing that makes you think page 1 is being shown twice? Also, the line `pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem());` does nothing so you might as well remove it.

Comment: Well, pager.getCurrentItem() logs '0' so I thought to use it instead of pager.setCurrentItem(0) in order to avoid magic numbers...

Comment: Page 0 never shows up - Page 1 is the intitial screen. The upon a right swipe, Page 1 shows up again, then Page 2 and then Page 3. Only once I get to Page 3 can I go all the way back to Page 0...

Comment: Have you tried putting 0 explicitly in that `pager.setCurrentItem` statement?

Comment: I have... I saw that mentioned in several answers here, and it doesn't change any thing in the logs or in the onscreen results... :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I solved my own (root) issue (though not the weird index-case that i was experiencing).

My misconception around the instantiation of individual content for each page in the ViewPager was that there would be a single Fragment used over and over, and I would pass arguments to it's constructor in order to tell it which layout to inflate.

Instead, I realized that I should have wholly separate Fragment classes, each owning it's own unique layout, and I could use the same position id from getItem() in the FragmentStatePagerAdapter to instantiate the correct Fragment... makes sense to me now.

See code below:

```
public class TutorialScreen extends FragmentActivity {

    private static final int NUM_PAGES = 3;
    private ViewPager pager; 
    private PagerAdapter adapter; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tutorial_layout);

        // Instantiate Pager & Adapter
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        adapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(pager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
        else {
            pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem() -1);
        }
    }

    // PagerAdapter SubClass
    private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment fragment;
            switch(position) {
                case 0:
                    fragment = new TutorialPage1();
                break;
                case 1:
                    fragment = new TutorialPage2();
                break;
                case 2:
                    fragment = new TutorialPage3();
                break;
                default:
                    fragment = new TutorialPage1();
                break;
            }
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }

    } /* EOC */

} /* EOC */
```

Comment: fragment on your code called twice every load and rotate phone, could you fix that?

Comment: Hmm... yes, but I think that's out of scope from the original question...

Comment: could you review my code? please. i have this problem and i cant fiex that

Comment: Post a new question and link it here

Comment: But what if you had, say twenty different fragments, and you just had to change a few things on each fragment, would you really want to create twenty different layouts?

Comment: No, you wouldn't, you would have some type of generator to inject/bind values from your model into your view..

Answer (score 0):

So, i'm using same fragments.
Adapter:

```
public class IncomeWeekFragmentAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    List<String> titlesList;
    List<String> reqDates;

    public IncomeWeekFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<String> titles, List<String> reqDates) {
        super(fm);
        this.titlesList = titles;
        this.reqDates = reqDates;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        if(fragment==null)
        fragment = new IncomeWeekFragment();
        if (position == 0) {
            args.putString("date_start", reqDates.get(1));
            args.putString("date_end", reqDates.get(0));
        } else if (position == 1) {
            args.putString("date_start", reqDates.get(3));
            args.putString("date_end", reqDates.get(2));
        } else if (position == 2) {
            args.putString("date_start", reqDates.get(5));
            args.putString("date_end", reqDates.get(4));
        } else if (position == 3) {
            args.putString("date_start", reqDates.get(7));
            args.putString("date_end", reqDates.get(6));
        }
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return COUNT_INCOME_FRAGMENT;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(@NonNull Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return titlesList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
change 1 with the number of fragments